# in an ECS framework why are components indexed via their name rather than an Enum?

Tags: entity-system, entity-component

I have been reading through a number of discussions on ECS framework and very often I see components being referred to via name rather than through a string object such as an `enum` or a `struct`.

I'm starting to build a test implementation myself and feel as though they should have a strong type rather than a string so that I can pick the component I am looking for from a list rather than 'guessing' with a string.

As an example you will often see:

```
Entity.GetComponent("Position");
```

rather than:

```
Entity.GetComponent(ComponentTypes.Position);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECS are especially good at data driven development and not hard coded by the programmer, this is why you see the usage pattern of string identifiers (in addition to the problems of merging multiple sources using enums and not colliding spaces).

Maps are pretty fast unless you're running thousands of them per frame, in which case something else needs fixing.  Some people use a pre-compile step that wraps the string ("Position") with an identifier that turns it into a CRC at compile time so it runs even faster.

You can keep up a reference window with all your component strings, if you want to build entities in code.

Comment: What do you mean by CRC? The CRC I'm familiar with is a cyclic redundancy check which is used for error detection?

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite what he means is calculating a hash code, using a CRC32 derived function (hash functions are used for different reasons and not only for checksum or fast lookup, even for encryption, functions with high distribution of values are usually used for lookups), this is usually run as a pre-build step where every string is replaced by a hash code.

Comment: I see, so basically it means converting strings to random unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you want that the ECS can be used in multiple projects and can always be extended.
If you use an `enum` in an ECS library, the user cannot create his own components without changing the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the string like this it's easy to avoid it.

```
const string POSITION = "position";
```

Then you can use the const identifier to refer to the entity instead of the string itself. This could help reduce the amount of typos. The reasons why you want strings have already been provided by @Patrick Hughes. Like mentioned Hashes are fast and the memory access is unlikely to cause performance issues. There are ways to boost performance but using enums is not going to contribute to that and is against the purpose of ECS.